# Is there still a possibility to blit a video on a PyGame surface?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

The pygame.movie package is deprecated and I haven't found an alternative to blit a video on a surface (background for example) and blit other objects on the foreground? That's not possible with moviepy etc. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing, unless if you want to upload every frame of the video as an image and play them frame by frame.